# Including 3rd party python module in c++ application

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7, numpy, module

I am trying to build an application to parse netCDF4 files in c++.

What I have done:

- Succeeded in parsing the files in python scripts.

What I need help with:

- Including my python script as a module. When I run my C++ program it complains that it can't access numPy.

What I Know:

- I fixed the same issue with the netCDF4 by copying the netCDF4.pyd file where my c++ executable was located, but cannot find the numPy. equivalent.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! I hope I understand the question correctly - is it importing a python module into c++? If that is so, try the following tutorial: [Embedding Python in C/C++: Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I).

Basically, to paraphrase, DON'T use code conversion or translation - it is unnecessairly complex. Just make the python code communicate with the C code as follows. Kudos to website above for the code, comments by me.

```
#include <Python.h> //get the scripts to interact

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pValue; //Arguments that are required.

if (argc < 3) 
{
    printf("Usage: exe_name python_source function_name\n");
    return 1;
}

// Allow your program to understand python
Py_Initialize();

// Initialize Name
pName = PyString_FromString(argv[1]);

// Import the module from python
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);

// pDict is a borrowed reference 
pDict = PyModule_GetDict(pModule);

// same situiation as above 
pFunc = PyDict_GetItemString(pDict, argv[2]);

if (PyCallable_Check(pFunc)) 
{
    PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, NULL);
} else 
{
    PyErr_Print();
}

// Tidy Everything Up.
Py_DECREF(pModule);
Py_DECREF(pName);

// End interpreter
Py_Finalize();

return 0;
}
```

I suggest you read the above tutorial, though.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I was actually going by that tutorial. It looks like the PyImport_Import(pName) call fails in my case.  I have a temp.py file that contains a bit of code to retrieve a temperature from a netcdf file.  The temp.py has a function defined just like the tutorial does, but it also has an import "from netcdf4 import Dataset" and the netcdf module imports numpy, which is causing the error because numpy cannot be found.  Have you seen this type of error before?